# Maven looking for non-existent artifact

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a maven project called X that has 2 sub-jars called:
Xa and Xb. When I build X, the jar includes Xa and Xb. I have just pushed X to Nexus. I also push Xb to Nexus, because a separate project, Y depends on it.
I have pushed a new version of X to Nexus, X-1.2. As a consequence, a new version of Xb-1.2 has also been pushed to Nexus.

In project Y, I want to use this new version of Xb (Xb-1.2) so I update Y's pom to reflect this. When I build Y, I get the following:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.Xb:Xb:jar:1.2:  Failure to
>   find com.X:X:pom:1.2 in 
>   http://nexus.abc.extranet.group/nexus/content/groups/maven-123 was
>   cached in the local repository,  resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of abc has elapsed or updates are forced ->
>   [Help 1]

What I find confusing is this line:

> Could not find artifact com.X:X:pom:1.2

Why is maven trying to look for a jar called X1.2 when my pom is Y doesn't depend on it. Granted, X1.2 is the parent project of Xb1.2, but X1.2 has been pushed to Nexus as it's own artifact.
When I look in Nexus, I cannot see an artifact called X1.2. When I open Xb's pom, I see it references its parent X1.2 - the very artifact maven cannot find. Why is it looking for Xb's parent?

Project X has been building successfully in this fashion for months. The issue I am having is only when I bumped up the version of Xb in project Y.

EDIT: I have found an error in the building of project X:

> [INFO] Searching for local aggregator root... [INFO] Local aggregation
>   root: /home/sc-jenkins/workspace/X [INFO] Processing change of
>   com.x:x:1.1 -> 1.2 [ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/jenkins/workspace/x/x (No such file or directory)

The extra x in the above directory path must be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question a little confusing, but I try to answer as best as I can: If your project Y depends on Xb which has a parent pom X, then X needs to be there as well. The reason: Maven transitively resolves dependencies, and parent poms can also define (or alter) dependencies. This means that a dependency of Xb could have been defined in the parent pom and Maven needs to have a look.

Comment: It makes sense that X needs to be there as well but I don;t understand how bumping a version of Xb has caused this issue. The reason I'm bumping Xb to Xb1.2 is because someone in the Ops team deleted Xb1.1. Maybe they also deleted X1.1 and X1.2 hasn't been created.